# Saving file data from current position to end of file with fstream

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

I have a situation where I loop through the first 64 lines of a file and save each line into a string. The rest of the file is unknown. It may be a single line or many. 
I know that there will be 64 lines at the beginning of the file but I do not know their size.

How can I save the entirety of the rest of the file to a string?

This is what I currently have:

```
std::ifstream signatureFile(fileName);

for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    std::string tempString;
    //read the line
    signatureFile >> tempString;
    //do other processing of string
}
std::string restOfFile;
//save the rest of the file into restOfFile
```

Thanks to the responses this is how I got it working:

```
std::ifstream signatureFile(fileName);

for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    std::string tempString;
    //read the line
    //using getline prevents extra line break when reading the rest of file
    std::getline(signatureFile, tempString);
    //do other processing of string
}

//save the rest of the file into restOfFile
std::string restOfFile{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{signatureFile},
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} };
signatureFile.close();
```

Comment: rest of file can be greater than RAM size even one string can exceed that size. So to read unknown amount of data use read+gcount

Comment: You are not actually reading *lines*, you are reading *words*. Take a look at [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Thanks!! This just saved me. I was getting an extra line when I used Sam's method. Using getline fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of `std::string`'s constructors is a template that takes two iterators as parameters, a beginning and an ending iterator, and constructs a string from the sequence defined by the iterators.

It just so happens that [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/istreambuf_iterator) provides a suitable input iterator for iterating over the contents of an input stream:

```
std::string restOfFile{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{signatureFile},
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
```

Comment: I'm a little confused how istreambuf_iterators work. How can I get the current position after the for loop and set it to an iterator?

Comment: You don't. The iterator does it for you. You just pass the file stream object to the iterator constructor, and it will iterate starting from the current position. Just like in the example I showed in my answer.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a shot. So the second argument means that it will continue to write to the string until it hits end of file?

Comment: The second argument evaluates to an iterator value that represents the end of the file. As I explained, this `std::string` constructor takes two iterators as parameters: the iterator to the beginning of a character sequence, an an iterator to the end of the character sequence. The constructed string consists of the characters in the sequence. The first parameter is an iterator to the current position in the file. The second parameter is an iterator that represents the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string buffer.

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

stringbuf buf;
signatureFile.get(buf);
string restOfFile = buf.str();
```